# Translate WP theme doesn't work

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a theme and I want to translate some test from english to spanish. After edit the .po and .mo files I did the following:

1. Rename files to `newsgrid-es_ES.mo` and `newsgrid-es_ES.po`
2. Copied the files to directories `/wp-content/themes/newsgrid/languages` and `/wp-content/languages` (just in case)
3. Add this code to my functions.php file: `$lang = TEMPLATE_PATH . '/languages';   load_theme_textdomain('newsgrid', $lang)`

But text remains in english, what I did forget?

**UPDATE**

This is how translations look in my theme files:

```
<?php _e( 'This is somewhat embarrassing, isn&rsquo;t it?', 'siiimple' ); ?>
<?php wp_link_pages(array('before' => '<div class="page-links"><span class="page-links-title">' . __('Pages:', 'siiimple') . '</span>', 'after' => '</div>', 'link_before' => '<span>', 'link_after' => '</span>')); ?>
```

I changed files name in all places to `siiimple-es_ES` but still not working

Comment: Show us some code. How do you print out text?

Comment: @FractalizeR I added that info to main post, please take a look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the documentation for [`_e`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_e) and [`load_theme_textdomain`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.7.1/src/wp-includes/l10n.php#L609). Your file name must be `<LOCALE>.mo`.

The second parameter passed to `_e` must be the textdomain, not the file name:

```
<?php _e( 'This is somewhat embarrassing, isn&rsquo;t it?', 'newsgrid' ); ?>
```